# Event Not fire view to controller and not pass values in controller in mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am sharing js code and controller code, when I enter values then I debug js code and show this values:

```
{"ReqID":"2","ReqNo":"000002","ReqDate":"21/09/2018","Job":"f","Approvedby":"f","IsApproved":"true","items":[{"Srno":"1","ItemCode":"018-0002","qty":"2","Remarks":"f"},{"Srno":"2","ItemCode":"028-0003","qty":"3","Remarks":"fff"},{"Srno":"3","ItemCode":"028-0010","qty":"7","Remarks":"ggg"}],"mSaveReq":"AddNew"}
```

but from the view to the controller the value is not passed, it only shows a js alert Error, I don't know what is the problem. The value passes correctly but why does this not pass the value to the controller?

**Javascript**

```
  <script>
        //Show model
        function addNewOrder()
        {
            $("#NewOrderForm").modal();
        }


        // Add Multiple Record
        $("#addToList").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($.trim($("#ItemCode").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Qty").val()) == "" || $.trim($("#Remarks").val()) == "") return;


            var Srno = document.getElementById("detailsTable").rows.length;
                ItemCode = $("#ItemCode").val(),
                qty = $("#Qty").val(),
                Remarks = $("#Remarks").val(),
                detailsTableBody = $("#detailsTable tbody");
                var ReqItems = '<tr><td>' + Srno + '</td><td>' + ItemCode + '</td><td>' + qty + '</td><td>' + Remarks + '</td><td> <a data-itemId="0" href="#" class="deleteItem">Remove</a></td></tr>';
            detailsTableBody.append(ReqItems);
            clearItem();
        });
            //After Add A New Order In The List
            function clearItem()
            {
                $("#ItemCode").val('');
                $("#Qty").val('');
                $("#Remarks").val('');

            }


            // After Add A New Order In The List, If You Want, You Can Remove

            $(document).on('click', 'a.deleteItem', function (e)

            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $self = $(this);
                if ($(this).attr('data-itemId') == "0") {
                    $(this).parents('tr').css("background-color", "white").fadeOut(800, function () {
                        $(this).remove();
                    });
                }
            });
                    //After Click Save Button Pass All Data View To Controller For Save Database

            function saveRequisition(data) {

                return $.ajax({
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/Home/RequisitionInsert", // function save
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {

                        alert(result);
                        location.reload();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error!")
                    }
                });

            }

            //Collect Multiple Order List For Pass To Controller

            $("#saveRequisition").click(function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var requisitionArr = [];
                requisitionArr.length = 0;

                $.each($("#detailsTable tbody tr"), function () {

                    requisitionArr.push({
                        Srno: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').html(),
                        ItemCode: $(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),
                        qty: $(this).find('td:eq(2)').html(),
                        Remarks: $(this).find('td:eq(3)').html()

                    });
                });

                var data = JSON.stringify({
                    ReqID: $("#ReqID").val(),
                    ReqNo: $("#ReqNo").val(),
                    ReqDate: $("#ReqDate").val(),
                    Job: $("#Job").val(),
                    Approvedby: $("#Approvedby").val(),
                    IsApproved: $("#IsApproved").val(),
                    items: requisitionArr,
                    mSaveReq: $("#mSaveReq").val()
                });

                $.when(saveRequisition(data)).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }).fail(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        });




    </script>
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult RequisitionInsert(string ReqID, string ReqNo,string ReqDate, string Job,string Approvedby,bool IsApproved, Requisition[] items, bool mSaveReq)
        {
            try
            {
                 objclsRequisition.RequisitionInsert(ReqID, ReqNo,ReqDate, Job,Approvedby,IsApproved, items,mSaveReq);

                 ViewBag.Message = "Your record has been inserted Successfully";
                 ModelState.Clear();

                return RedirectToAction("Requisition", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }

 public int RequisitionInsert(string ReqID, string ReqNo, string ReqDate, string Job, string Approvedby, bool IsApproved, Requisition[] items, bool AddNew)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                tr = con.BeginTransaction();

                if (AddNew)
                {
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(Req_ID), 0) + 1 from RequisitionMain", con);
                    ReqID = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(CAST(ReqNo as int)),0)+1 from RequisitionMain where Comp_ID=1 and GL_Year='2018-2019'", con);
                    ReqNo = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString().PadLeft(6, '0');

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RequisitionMainInsert", con);
                }
                else
                    cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RequisitionMainUpdate", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Req_ID", ReqID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqNo", ReqNo);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", "1");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GL_Year", "2018-2019");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqDate", DateTime.Parse(ReqDate).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Job", Job);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApprovedBy", Approvedby);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["AgentName"]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsApproved", IsApproved);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Transaction = tr;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                string mRowState = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(mRowState == "Deleted")
                    {
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("delete from RequisitionDetail where Req_ID_Det=" + items[i].Req_ID_Det + "", con);
                        cmd.Transaction = tr;
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (mRowState == "Added")
                    {
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ISNULL(MAX(Req_ID_Det), 0) + 1 from RequisitionDetail", con);
                        Int64 mReqID_Det = Convert.ToInt64(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RequisitionDetailInsert", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Req_ID_Det", mReqID_Det);
                    }

                    else if (mRowState == "Modified")
                    {
                        cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_RequisitionDetailUpdate", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Req_ID_Det", items[i].Req_ID_Det);
                    }

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Req_ID", ReqID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReqNo", ReqNo);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comp_ID", "1");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GL_Year", "2018-2019");

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SrNo", i + 1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCode", items[i].ItemCode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", Convert.ToDecimal(items[i].Qty));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Remarks", items[i].Remarks);

                    cmd.Transaction = tr;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                tr.Commit();
                return i;
            }
            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw sqlex;  // read all sql error 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                tr.Rollback();
                throw ex; // General execption

            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're calling `RequisitionInsert` from AJAX, it should use `return Json` instead of `return RedirectToAction` (you cannot redirect to another action using AJAX, since no JSON data returned you're getting error alert).

Comment: i have changed return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); but still same alert message "Error"

Comment: Try setting breakpoint inside controller action, is it get hit? If doesn't, the `data` part supplied from AJAX may be wrong (I found out `bool mSaveReq` but you're passing `"mSaveReq":"AddNew"` which should use `string mSaveReq`).

Comment: Not its not getting hit to controller.

Comment: Well, I think you're passing wrong argument for `mSaveReq` as explained above, hence the controller method doesn't hit. The `"AddNew"` string value cannot converted directly to `bool` data type, you must use `switch` block for it or pass `true`/`false` value.

Comment: Problem Resolved Thanks Tetsuya